# Is there any way to export the contents of my Teams Chats for one day, by chat and time?

Tags: powershell, microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams

Is there any way to get and list out all my conversations in teams chats for one day? When I'm logging time, I lose track of what I worked on when I'm helping others, and the find function just gives me 8 messages on a big screen, which means I have to scroll through dozens of screens to get the "oh, this is what we're doing". I'd rather have a list with the chat name, time, and what was said.  Powershell, CLI, KQL, don't care how. Thanks.

```
John Doe Chat: Doe, John [10:35] what is this about
John Doe Chat: Me, Myself [10:36] trying to come up with an example
PeopleChatOne: Joe [10:37] what are we, chopped liver?
```

Comment: This is not a coding service website, we expect some debugging and attempt at solving the problem on your behalf.

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon that's fair, but there's woefully little to even start with.  I found https://github.com/pnp/cli-microsoft365/issues/2860 which talks about it, https://pnp.github.io/cli-microsoft365/cmd/teams/chat/chat-get/ , not to mention https://o365reports.com/2020/05/28/microsoft-teams-reporting-using-powershell/ and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/dawiese/get-office365-usage-reports-from-the-microsoft-graph-using-windows-powershell. Just a "here's where to start" would be a huge help.

Comment: You can use AzureAD and Graph API to do this. There’s an excellent write up here. -https://github.com/leeford/Backup-TeamsChat

Comment: @anothervictimofthemouse that looks perfect! Thanks! Now to go grovel for permissions.

Comment: @mbourgon-Could you please confirm if your issue has resolved with above suggestion or still looking for any help?

Comment: @Sayali-MSFT I still need some help, because the LeeFord code referenced above uses the protected API access, which grants you access to ALL users' messages - and they're never going to give me that.

Comment: There is no way to do this via the client. If you are ok with a programmatic solution, use the  Export API-https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/export-teams-content#how-to-access-teams-export-apis

Comment: @Sayali-MSFT I tried logging into Graph Explorer and running GET for `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{myidhere}/chats/getAllMessages`, but got `"Requested API is not supported in delegated context"`. My client request ID was  "b81b43a8-dc84-ce56-fc06-f46021c905da"

Comment: @Sayali-MSFT also getting "Missing scope permissions on the request. API requires one of 'Chat.ReadBasic, Chat.Read, Chat.ReadWrite'", which is strange, I would assume I could look at my own messages?  UPDATE: okay, figured out how to grant Graph Explorer access, I'm able to at least do something now.  Now to figure out how to do this through powershell or some other CLI.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update 4/2023** *- I added filters to this. There are two possible filters, one to filter the chats retrieved, and one to filter messages in the chats (finally found a way to do it). Given that I have over 1500 total chats at this point, filtering the chats is a necessity. Meetings, at least mine, have frequent changes - new people, people removed, name changes, etc. This isn't the case on oneonone and groups, alas. So: filter down the meetings to those with changes in the past couple of weeks, grab all other chats, then run each of them using a filter on get-mgchatmessage to only get recent messages. See code at bottom. You could probably do something to chnage the name of recent chats, but I haven't looked at that yet.*

Okay, after digging for a bit... turns out the answer is, as @sayali-msft and @anothervictimofthemouse mentioned, is the Graph API - which has a module. Note that you DO have a certain amount of access to your own stuff without needing an admins help, but you will have to explicitly grant it to each "application" that will connect to it. And there's a good amount of playing you can do with the Graph Explorer.

The below code will grab all of your chats, then grab the most recent 200 messages, filtered for the past day, and then will return the pertinent info.

Still missing at this point:

- time zones seem wonky, specifically people in other time zones.
- piping to OGV gives you all lines, when I really only want the first.
- Fortunately, format-table DOES limit to one line per message
- stripping out HTML works but is not great.

members may not be working.

```
Install-Module Microsoft.Graph
Import-Module Microsoft.Graph.Teams
$RequiredScopes = @("Chat.ReadBasic", "Chat.ReadWrite")
Connect-MgGraph -Scopes $RequiredScopes
#at this point a browser window should appear - allow it.
#I had to find my user id in graph explorer UI by running GET   V1.0    https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me
#unsure how to get it otherwise - but you don't need it with get-mgchat
get-mgchat
#take one of those IDs
#let's look at this chat:
get-mgchat  -ChatId 19:deadbeefb2d949d88d4455f5279e5d8b@thread.v2
get-mgchatmessage -ChatId 19:deadbeefb2d949d88d4455f5279e5d8b@thread.v2 

#this nests and walks through properly, strips HTML, but lord this will be slow.  And shows more than one line per message, even when I try now to.
#By default you can get all your chats by running get-mgchat.  -all and -pagesize 50 is required for the module to paginate the request and get you everything. But in my case it grabbed all 2000 chats. The -first 5 is for testing.
$tzone = Get-TimeZone  # conversion from GMT to local time. https://jdhitsolutions.com/blog/powershell/7962/convert-to-local-time-with-powershell/
$mychats = get-mgchat -all -PageSize 50  |select -first 5
$all_chat_info = @() #force-setting to an array
$all_chat_info = foreach ($chat in $mychats) { 
    $chatinfo = get-mgchat -ChatId $chat.id #get base details about the CHAT itself
    #set some details about the chat itself for the later query
    $chatname = $chat.Topic
    $members = $chat.Members
    $chattype = $chat.chattype
    #now get every message from that chat since midnight yesterday.  Note LastModifiedDateTime is GMT.    The jdhit page says -($tzone...), but all I had to do was .tolocaltime() ... I think.
    #the -top 200 -pagesize 50 is to get the most recent 200 messages, and again you have to paginate.   
    $recentchatmessages = get-mgchatmessage -ChatId $chat.id -top 200 -pagesize 50 |where {$_.LastModifiedDateTime.tolocaltime() -gt (get-date).date.AddDays(-1)} # all from after midnight yesterday |select -first 5
    #and now use select expression to add the above fields and parse the below fields, stripping out HTML (but I can't seem to only get the first line in OGV)
    $recentchatmessages | select @{Label='LastModified';Expression={($_.LastModifiedDateTime.tolocaltime())}}, @{Label='ChatName';Expression={($chatname)}}, @{Label='members';Expression={($members)}}, @{Label='ChatType';Expression={($chattype)}}, 
    @{Label='From';Expression={($_.from.user.displayname)}}, @{Label='Body';Expression={ ($_.Body.content -split '\n')[0] -replace '<[^>]+>',''}}
    #@{Label='From';Expression={($_.from.user.displayname)}}, @{Label='Body';Expression={( ($_.Body.content -replace '<[^>]+>','').split([Environment]::NewLine)|select -first 1)}}
}
$all_chat_info|format-table 
#and now close/disconnect
Disconnect-MgGraph
```

Several problems present themselves:

- All and PageSize appear broken (update: use "-all -pagesize 50")
- Expanding the fields. Probably trivial for others, but a pain for me.
  currently comes back like

  Microsoft.Graph.PowerShell.Models.MicrosoftGraphItemBody
  Microsoft.Graph.PowerShell.Models.MicrosoftGraphChatMessageFromIdentitySet

Some references I found while getting it working.

https://practical365.com/connect-microsoft-graph-powershell-sdk/  - getting the scope set
graph explorer
https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/Microsoft.Graph/1.9.2
https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-powershell - the github for the actual modules. the readme is gold specifically https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-powershell/blob/dev/samples/5-Teams.ps1

**Newer code that uses -filter on meetings/chats, then -filter messages**

```
$RequiredScopes = @("Chat.ReadBasic", "Chat.ReadWrite")
Connect-MgGraph -Scopes $RequiredScopes
$startdate = (get-date).AddDays(-5) #look for chats less than 5 days old
$meetingchanged = (get-date).AddDays(-14) #lookback for meeting changes, only include meetings with changes more recent than this
$myrecentchats = @() 
$myrecentchats = get-mgchat -all -PageSize 50 -filter "lastUpdatedDateTime gt $($meetingchanged.ToString("s") + "Z") and ChatType eq 'meeting'"
$myrecentchats += get-mgchat -all -PageSize 50 -filter "ChatType eq 'oneOnOne'"
$myrecentchats += get-mgchat -all -PageSize 50 -filter "ChatType eq 'group'"

$all_chat_info = foreach ($chat in $myrecentchats) {
    $chatinfo = get-mgchat -ChatId $chat.id #get base details about the CHAT itself
    #set some details about the chat itself for the later query
    $chatname = $chat.Topic
    $members = $chat.Members
    $chattype = $chat.chattype
    $recentchatmessages = get-mgchatmessage -ChatId $chat.id  -Filter "lastModifiedDateTime gt $($startdate.ToString("s") + "Z")"
    #and now use select expression to add the above fields and parse the below fields, stripping out HTML (but I can't seem to only get the first line in OGV)
    $recentchatmessages | select @{Label='LastModified';Expression={($_.LastModifiedDateTime.tolocaltime())}}, @{Label='ChatName';Expression={($chatname)}}, @{Label='members';Expression={($members)}}, @{Label='ChatType';Expression={($chattype)}}, 
    @{Label='From';Expression={($_.from.user.displayname)}}, @{Label='ChatID';Expression={($chat.id)}}, @{Label='Body';Expression={ ($_.Body.content -split '\n')[0] -replace '<[^>]+>',''}}, @{Label='LUDT';Expression={($chat.LastUpdatedDateTime)}}
}
$all_chat_info|ogv
```